# scikit learn spectral clustering affinity with precomputed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a similarity matrix which considers the similarity between each two users among the 80 users. I want to cluster the users based on this similarity matrix.

```
label = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=5 ,affinity='precomputed').fit_predict(lena)
```

is this the right way to call the similarity matrix and get the label? 
example: if we have three users, the matrix like[1,0.8,0;0.8,1,0;0,0,1] and get label like(1,1,2).

Furthermore, I want to use the Elbow method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set to set the right number of clusters. But its difficult to have right measurement for the performance. Any suggestions?

Comment: `lena` is an image, not a distance matrix.

Comment: @Anony-Moussehttp://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html. I see what you mean, but on this link, fit_predict(X, y=None)[source]
Performs clustering on X and returns cluster labels.
Parameters: X : ndarray, shape (n_samples, n_features) Input data.    Is that possible to consider each user's similarity between all the others' as the features of that user? Or otherwise, do you know when the affinity = precomputed,  where should the precomputed matrix being put? with many thanks

Comment: If it is not `lena` [aka: Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) but a matrix of yours, don't call the variable `lena`, please. That is misleading, because this is a very popular example.

Answer (score 0):

Same question here,  read the docs of sklearn but remains unclear.

From my investiguations:

```
given sc = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=5 ,affinity='precomputed')
```

`sc.fit_predict(similarity_matrix)` should do the trick. It assigns `similarity_matrix` to `sc.affinity_matrix_` and then performs clustering.